# RaspberryPi + Pocketsphinx + ps3eye Error: Failed to open audio device

Tags: raspbian, usb, hardware, audio, setup

just installed pocketsphinx on my raspberry pi. Think i'm going crazy but not sure if I'm providing the correct device.

Whenever I run:

> src/programs/pocketsphinx_continuous -adcdev plughw:1,0 -nfft 2048
>   -samprate 48000

I get the following:

> root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8#
>   src/programs/pocketsphinx_continuous -adcdev plughw:1,0 -nfft 2048
>   -samprate 48000  INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line: /usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8/src/programs/.libs/lt-pocketsphinx_continuous
>   \     -adcdev plughw:1,0 \    -nfft 2048 \    -samprate 48000
>
> Current configuration: [NAME]     [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
>   -adcdev               plughw:1,0
>   -agc      none        none
>   -agcthresh    2.0     2.000000e+00
>   -alpha        0.97        9.700000e-01
>   -argfile
>   -ascale       20.0        2.000000e+01
>   -aw       1       1
>   -backtrace    no      no
>   -beam     1e-48       1.000000e-48
>   -bestpath yes     yes
>   -bestpathlw   9.5     9.500000e+00
>   -bghist       no      no
>   -ceplen       13      13
>   -cmn      current     current
>   -cmninit  8.0     8.0
>   -compallsen   no      no
>   -debug                0
>   -dict
>   -dictcase no      no
>   -dither       no      no
>   -doublebw no      no
>   -ds       1       1
>   -fdict
>   -feat     1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
>   -featparams
>   -fillprob 1e-8        1.000000e-08
>   -frate        100     100
>   -fsg
>   -fsgusealtpron    yes     yes
>   -fsgusefiller yes     yes
>   -fwdflat  yes     yes
>   -fwdflatbeam  1e-64       1.000000e-64
>   -fwdflatefwid 4       4
>   -fwdflatlw    8.5     8.500000e+00
>   -fwdflatsfwin 25      25
>   -fwdflatwbeam 7e-29       7.000000e-29
>   -fwdtree  yes     yes
>   -hmm
>   -infile
>   -input_endian little      little
>   -jsgf
>   -kdmaxbbi -1      -1
>   -kdmaxdepth   0       0
>   -kdtree
>   -latsize  5000        5000
>   -lda
>   -ldadim       0       0
>   -lextreedump  0       0
>   -lifter       0       0
>   -lm
>   -lmctl
>   -lmname       default     default
>   -logbase  1.0001      1.000100e+00
>   -logfn
>   -logspec  no      no
>   -lowerf       133.33334   1.333333e+02
>   -lpbeam       1e-40       1.000000e-40
>   -lponlybeam   7e-29       7.000000e-29
>   -lw       6.5     6.500000e+00
>   -maxhmmpf -1      -1
>   -maxnewoov    20      20
>   -maxwpf       -1      -1
>   -mdef
>   -mean
>   -mfclogdir
>   -min_endfr    0       0
>   -mixw
>   -mixwfloor    0.0000001   1.000000e-07
>   -mllr
>   -mmap     yes     yes
>   -ncep     13      13
>   -nfft     512     2048
>   -nfilt        40      40
>   -nwpen        1.0     1.000000e+00
>   -pbeam        1e-48       1.000000e-48
>   -pip      1.0     1.000000e+00
>   -pl_beam  1e-10       1.000000e-10
>   -pl_pbeam 1e-5        1.000000e-05
>   -pl_window    0       0
>   -rawlogdir
>   -remove_dc    no      no
>   -round_filters    yes     yes
>   -samprate 16000       4.800000e+04
>   -seed     -1      -1
>   -sendump
>   -senlogdir
>   -senmgau
>   -silprob  0.005       5.000000e-03
>   -smoothspec   no      no
>   -svspec
>   -time     no      no
>   -tmat
>   -tmatfloor    0.0001      1.000000e-04
>   -topn     4       4
>   -topn_beam    0       0
>   -toprule
>   -transform    legacy      legacy
>   -unit_area    yes     yes
>   -upperf       6855.4976   6.855498e+03
>   -usewdphones  no      no
>   -uw       1.0     1.000000e+00
>   -var
>   -varfloor 0.0001      1.000000e-04
>   -varnorm  no      no
>   -verbose  no      no
>   -warp_params
>   -warp_type    inverse_linear  inverse_linear
>   -wbeam        7e-29       7.000000e-29
>   -wip      0.65        6.500000e-01
>   -wlen     0.025625    2.562500e-02
>
> INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line: \  -nfilt 20 \     -lowerf 1 \
>     -upperf 4000 \  -wlen 0.025 \   -transform dct \    -round_filters no \
>     -remove_dc yes \    -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 \  -feat 1s_c_d_dd \   -agc
>   none \    -cmn current \  -cmninit 56,-3,1 \  -varnorm no
>
> Current configuration: [NAME]     [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
>   -agc      none        none
>   -agcthresh    2.0     2.000000e+00
>   -alpha        0.97        9.700000e-01
>   -ceplen       13      13
>   -cmn      current     current
>   -cmninit  8.0     56,-3,1
>   -dither       no      no
>   -doublebw no      no
>   -feat     1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
>   -frate        100     100
>   -input_endian little      little
>   -lda
>   -ldadim       0       0
>   -lifter       0       0
>   -logspec  no      no
>   -lowerf       133.33334   1.000000e+00
>   -ncep     13      13
>   -nfft     512     2048
>   -nfilt        40      20
>   -remove_dc    no      yes
>   -round_filters    yes     no
>   -samprate 16000       4.800000e+04
>   -seed     -1      -1
>   -smoothspec   no      no
>   -svspec               0-12/13-25/26-38
>   -transform    legacy      dct
>   -unit_area    yes     yes
>   -upperf       6855.4976   4.000000e+03
>   -varnorm  no      no
>   -verbose  no      no
>   -warp_params
>   -warp_type    inverse_linear  inverse_linear
>   -wlen     0.025625    2.500000e-02
>
> INFO: acmod.c(246): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/feat.params
>   INFO: feat.c(713): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd',
>   ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none' INFO: cmn.c(142):
>   mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0 INFO: acmod.c(167): Using subvector
>   specification 0-12/13-25/26-38 INFO: mdef.c(517): Reading model
>   definition:
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef INFO:
>   mdef.c(528): Found byte-order mark BMDF, assuming this is a binary
>   mdef file INFO: bin_mdef.c(336): Reading binary model definition:
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef INFO:
>   bin_mdef.c(513): 50 CI-phone, 143047 CD-phone, 3 emitstate/phone, 150
>   CI-sen, 5150 Sen, 27135 Sen-Seq INFO: tmat.c(205): Reading HMM
>   transition probability matrices:
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/transition_matrices
>   INFO: acmod.c(121): Attempting to use SCHMM computation module INFO:
>   ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter:
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/means
>   INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1 codebook, 3 feature, size:  INFO:
>   ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13 INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13 INFO:
>   ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13 INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture
>   gaussian parameter:
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/variances
>   INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1 codebook, 3 feature, size:  INFO:
>   ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13 INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13 INFO:
>   ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13 INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 0 variance values
>   floored INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(903): Loading senones from dump file
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/sendump
>   INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(927): BEGIN FILE FORMAT DESCRIPTION INFO:
>   s2_semi_mgau.c(1022): Using memory-mapped I/O for senones INFO:
>   s2_semi_mgau.c(1296): Maximum top-N: 4 Top-N beams: 0 0 0 INFO:
>   dict.c(317): Allocating 137543 * 20 bytes (2686 KiB) for word entries
>   INFO: dict.c(332): Reading main dictionary:
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/en_US/cmu07a.dic INFO:
>   dict.c(211): Allocated 1010 KiB for strings, 1664 KiB for phones INFO:
>   dict.c(335): 133436 words read INFO: dict.c(341): Reading filler
>   dictionary:
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/noisedict
>   INFO: dict.c(211): Allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones INFO:
>   dict.c(344): 11 words read INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables
>   for dictionary INFO: dict2pid.c(404): Allocating 50^3 * 2 bytes (244
>   KiB) for word-initial triphones INFO: dict2pid.c(131): Allocated 30200
>   bytes (29 KiB) for word-final triphones INFO: dict2pid.c(195):
>   Allocated 30200 bytes (29 KiB) for single-phone word triphones INFO:
>   ngram_model_arpa.c(77): No \data\ mark in LM file INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(142): Will use memory-mapped I/O for LM file INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(196): ngrams 1=5001, 2=436879, 3=418286 INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(242):     5001 = LM.unigrams(+trailer) read INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(288):   436879 = LM.bigrams(+trailer) read INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(314):   418286 = LM.trigrams read INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(339):    37293 = LM.prob2 entries read INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(359):    14370 = LM.bo_wt2 entries read INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(379):    36094 = LM.prob3 entries read INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(407):      854 = LM.tseg_base entries read INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(463):     5001 = ascii word strings read INFO:
>   ngram_search_fwdtree.c(99): 788 unique initial diphones INFO:
>   ngram_search_fwdtree.c(147): 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 60
>   single-phone words INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(186): Creating search
>   tree INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(191): before: 0 root, 0 non-root
>   channels, 60 single-phone words INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(326):
>   after: max nonroot chan increased to 13428 INFO:
>   ngram_search_fwdtree.c(338): after: 457 root, 13300 non-root channels,
>   26 single-phone words INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(156): fwdflat:
>   min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25 INFO: continuous.c(371):
>   /usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8/src/programs/.libs/lt-pocketsphinx_continuous
>   COMPILED ON: Jul 21 2013, AT: 14:34:06
>
> Mixer load failed: Invalid argument FATAL_ERROR: "continuous.c", line
>   246: Failed to open audio device

I'm using a ps3eye currently. If i do a simple:

> arecord -D plughw:1,0 -d 5 -q -f cd -t wav ~/test.wav

Everything works fine ( Verified this by hooking up Raspberrypi to TV via HDMI and running aplay ~/test.wav )

What am I doing wrong guys?

Information you might need ( based on other posts i've seen ):

```
root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8# 
root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8# aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=ALSA
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA
    Default Audio Device
root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8#



root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8# dpkg -l | grep "alsa"
ii  alsa-base                             1.0.25+3~deb7u1                      all          ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-firmware-loaders                 1.0.25-2                             armhf        ALSA software loaders for specific hardware
ii  alsa-oss                              1.0.25-1                             armhf        ALSA wrapper for OSS applications
ii  alsa-tools                            1.0.25-2                             armhf        Console based ALSA utilities for specific hardware
ii  alsa-utils                            1.0.25-4                             armhf        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
ii  alsaplayer-alsa                       0.99.80-5.1                          armhf        PCM player designed for ALSA (ALSA output module)
ii  alsaplayer-common                     0.99.80-5.1                          armhf        PCM player designed for ALSA (common files)
ii  alsaplayer-gtk                        0.99.80-5.1                          armhf        PCM player designed for ALSA (GTK+ version)
ii  gstreamer0.10-alsa:armhf              0.10.36-1.1                          armhf        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
ii  libsox-fmt-alsa                       14.4.0-3                             armhf        SoX alsa format I/O library
root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8#



root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8# dpkg -l | grep pulseaudio
ii  gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio:armhf        0.10.31-3+nmu1                       armhf        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8#
```

Also in terms of installing pocket sphinx I did the following:

```
# uninstall pulse audio if its already installed 
apt-get remove pulseaudio -y 
aptitude purge pulseaudio -y

# sphinxbase install
apt-get install bison -y
cd /usr/install
wget  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/cmusphinx/sphinxbase/0.8/sphinxbase-0.8.tar.gz
tar -xvf sphinxbase-0.8.tar.gz
cd sphinxbase-0.8
./configure --enable-fixed
make
make install
cd -

# pocketsphinx installwget http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/pocketsphinx/0.8/pocketsphinx-0.8.tar.gz
tar -xvf pocketsphinx-0.8.tar.gz
cd pocketsphinx-0.8
./configure
make
make install
```

Any ideas or advice in the right direction would be extremely helpful.

Comment: When you do speech recognition with `arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f cd -t wav -d 3 -r 16000 | flac - -f --best --sample-rate 16000 -o out.flac; wget -O - -o /dev/null --post-file out.flac --header="Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=16000" http://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?lang=en | sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g' ; rm out.flac`, does it give you some JSON text output containing a resemblance of what you said?

Comment: Hey syb0rg, yup I do. I actually made a couple changes since yesterday which I documented here: http://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/1itr9h/how_to_compile_use_pocketsphinx_w_pulseaudio_on/ I think I finally got pocketsphinx to run, now I've created my .dict .lm and corpus files to try to recognize my commands, will report back tonight with results of this.

Comment: I noticed you posted a similar question on SO, and an answer there told you to use pulseaudio.  I preferred not to use pulseaudio, and went instead using only Alsa.  Just wondering, what is your reason for using PocketSphinx instead of Google?

Comment: So i'm actually using both, I want to use pocketsphinx as a keyword matcher, meaning....I want it to continuously be running in the back ground, then when I talk to the computer ( by saying "Scarlett"), it plays a sound and begins recording a wav file...when silence is detected, it saves the file, re-encodes it to flac, and sends it to google ( since google has such a high accuracy rate ). Didn't want to risk continuously sending google files and getting rate-limited. Seems like that was done here ( looks good too ): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSLtQ7iI4vk @syb0rg

Comment: I doubt you would get rate limited, but I can't guarantee that.  What language are you using to program this?

Comment: Actually I'm going to be using bash for a lot of it (whatever cli tools are available) , although for the "listening" daemon, i've seen at least 1 coded in python one w/ ruby and one in c. I'll probably use the c one if i decide to go that path, mainly because i'm familiar with c already and haven't coded in python before.... what are you using?

Comment: I started out with the intentions of using C++, but it morphed into C only.  I would definitely say I'm only in the alpha stages of development, but the project as a whole is coming along nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while, with with some help from a couple sources ( they will be listed in my answer ) and some helpful hints from nikolay-shmyrev ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/432021/nikolay-shmyrev ), I finally came up with an answer that worked for me.

Key assumptions:

1. running these commands as the pi user ( previously I was running them as root, which was incorrect )
2. I'm using continuous recognition and I was ONLY looking for the ability to "wake-up" my raspberry pi. Upon waking it up, I have other plans on how it should interact.

My setup:
1. Canakit RaspberryPi

2. HDMI cable to my Toshiba TV
3. usb wifi dongle
4. Playstation 3 Eye for speech recognition

Moving forward. I ran the following commands on my RaspberryPi to get PulseAudio + pocketsphinx working together w/ my Playstation 3 Eye. ( If you see any places for improvement please let me know )

```
# Install pulse audio / development packages
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio libao4 libasound2-plugins libgconfmm-2.6-1c2 libglademm-2.4-1c2a libpulse-dev libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse-mainloop-glib0-dbg libpulse0 libpulse0-dbg libsox-fmt-pulse paman paprefs pavucontrol pavumeter pulseaudio pulseaudio-dbg pulseaudio-esound-compat pulseaudio-esound-compat-dbg pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf pulseaudio-module-jack pulseaudio-module-lirc pulseaudio-module-lirc-dbg pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-module-zeroconf pulseaudio-module-zeroconf-dbg pulseaudio-utils -y

# per instructions from http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=12497
sudo \cp -pf /etc/asound.conf /etc/asound.conf.ORIG 
sudo echo 'pcm.pulse {
    type pulse
}

ctl.pulse {
    type pulse
}

pcm.!default {
    type pulse
}

ctl.!default {
    type pulse
}' > /etc/asound.conf

_DEVICE_LOAD_ON_START=$(grep "snd.bcm2835" /etc/modules | wc -l)
if [[ "${_DEVICE_LOAD_ON_START}" = "0" ]]; then

  sudo \cp -pf /etc/modules /etc/modules.ORIG
  sudo echo "snd-bcm2835" >> /etc/modules

fi

_DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING=$(grep "DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING=1" /etc/default/pulseaudio | wc -l)
if [[ "${_DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING}" = "0" ]]; then

  sudo \cp -pf /etc/default/pulseaudio /etc/default/pulseaudio.ORIG
  sudo sed -i "s,DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING=1,DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING=0,g" /etc/default/pulseaudio

fi

sudo \cp -fvp /etc/pulse/system.pa /etc/pulse/system.pa.ORIG
sudo echo "
# ScarlettPi ADDED THIS
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/24 auth-anonymous=1
load-module module-zeroconf-publish" >> /etc/pulse/system.pa

sudo echo "
# ScarlettPi added this
#load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
#load-module module-zeroconf-publish
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/24 auth-anonymous=1
load-module module-zeroconf-publish" >> /etc/pulse/default.pa

# check to make sure it looks okay
cat /etc/pulse/default.pa

# change default driver frm alsa to pulse
sudo \cp -fvp /etc/libao.conf /etc/libao.conf.ORIG
sudo sed -i "s,default_driver=alsa,default_driver=pulse,g" /etc/libao.conf 

# settings according to Pi-Musicbox ( https://github.com/woutervanwijk/Pi-MusicBox )
sudo \cp -fvp /etc/pulse/daemon.conf /etc/pulse/daemon.conf.ORIG

sudo echo "
# ScarlettPi added this
high-priority = yes
nice-level = 5
exit-idle-time = -1
resample-method = src-sinc-medium-quality
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 2" >> /etc/pulse/daemon.conf.ORIG

# add pi to the pulse access group
sudo adduser pi pulse-access

sudo shutdown -r now


# install python dev packages
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev -y

# sphinxbase install
sudo apt-get install bison -y
cd ~pi/
wget  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/cmusphinx/sphinxbase/0.8/sphinxbase-0.8.tar.gz
tar -xvf sphinxbase-0.8.tar.gz
cd sphinxbase-0.8
./configure
make
sudo make install

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

echo "
# scarlettPi added this
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig" >> ~/.bashrc

cd ~pi/
# pocketsphinx install
# set this: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/pocketsphinxlibs /usr/local/bin/pocketsphinx_continuous
# http://www.voxforge.org/home/forums/message-boards/speech-recognition-engines/howto-use-pocketsphinx
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/pocketsphinx/0.8/pocketsphinx-0.8.tar.gz
tar -xvf pocketsphinx-0.8.tar.gz
cd pocketsphinx-0.8
./configure
make
sudo make install

cd ~pi/
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinxtrain/1.0.8/sphinxtrain-1.0.8.tar.gz
tar -xvf sphinxtrain-1.0.8
cd sphinxtrain-1.0.8
./configure
make
sudo make install

# try using it:

sudo apt-get install oss-compat -y

# check if pulse daemon is running
ps aux | grep pulse

# If it isn't, start it up yourself ( need to figure out the best way to make this run on boot...init.d script maybe? )
# forgot where I grabbed this line from, but this was put into my rc.local ( didn't start up my pulseaudio daemon automatically though )
su - pi -c '/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog --system=false'

# check again to see if pule daemon is now running
ps aux | grep pulse

cd cd ~pi/pocketsphinx-0.8
# IMPORTANT NOTE, YOU HAVE TO BE USER PI AND THE PULSEAUDIO SERVER NEEDS TO BE RUNNING
# advice taken from: http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/49e34dff/ ( on how to calibrate pocketsphinx correctly )
# from: on how to get pocketsphinx to recognize new words via a corpus: http://www.ghatage.com/2012/12/make-pocketsphinx-recognize-new-words/
# and finally from: http://puneetk.com/basics-of-java-speech-grammar-format-jsgf BEST/Simplest explanation of how Java Speech Grammar Format ( JSGF ) works
# NOTE: assume I already created my corpus file, .jsgf file, .dic, and .lm files ( via http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool.html ) 
pocketsphinx_continuous -lm /home/pi/scarlettPi/config/speech/lm/scarlett.lm -dict /home/pi/scarlettPi/config/speech/dict/scarlett.dic -hmm /home/pi/scarlettPi/config/speech/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k -silprob  0.1 -wip 1e-4 -bestpath 0
```

I plan on adding more details behind why I used certain setting, configurations in a blog post i'm writing on my home automation project, but figured, i'd share what i've done thus far incase someone else was stuck like me and would like to move forward with what they're working on. Hope this helps someone. Thanks for the advice guys.